# First brillouin zone propagation wave vector components in special surface cuts in cubic systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

I'm trying to figure out a context in an article about the allowed in plane propagation wave vector , in specific surface cuts or orientations such as (001) (110) (111) where the authors gave the first brillouin zone of each cubic lattice and hence the parallel wave vector k// with two components k1 and k2.

Well I didn't know the relationship between the reciprocal basis with k// or with the plotted brillouin zone ( square, rectangle or hexagon) and how could they get the k// components (in Table 3 page 21 Second picture)?

Here's some of pictures from the article to get my point.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, you look at the surface of choice and determine in-plane and out-of-plane vectors. You really haven't said anything about just why you have confusion. Look at Table 1 - can you see why those real space bases are chosen? If so, Table 2 follows quite naturally.

Comment: Yes I didn't know how the authors calculate the components k1 and k2 in the table 3 , it must be a relation joining the reciprocal basis and k// or it's the allowed surface area calculated or transformation of representation, I'm stucked on the basics I think!